# type exists in both dlls with dynamically loaded dll

Tags: .net, managed-c++

I have not found this scenario yet and am having difficulties finding a solution. I have a .Net app attempting to dynamically load a managed C++ dll to perform a task that should return an array of Data.Model.Viper objects. I also have that exact object defined in my .Net code. So when I call the managed C++ method I get back the data I want but when I try to use it I cannot call it a Data.Model.Viper list. Since it is dynamically loaded I cannot find a way to alias it and even if I do I am not sure I can convert the C++ Data.Model.Viper list into the .Net Data.Model.Viper list.

Anyone worked through something like this? Alternative ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that namespaces completely the same?

Comment: Yes, the managed C++ dll uses a header file that gets generated from a .Net webservice so the base data models are exact copies. I now need to use this managed C++ dll within the website.

Comment: Can you wrap it into another assembly where it will expose same type under different namespace, or can you just change namespace of your duplicating object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work, type identity in .NET prevents this.  A strong DLL Hell countermeasure.  Type identity of a type isn't just its namespace name and type name but also the assembly it came from.  So you have **two** distinctive Data.Model.Viper types and they have no relationship with each other at all.  Trying to cast just produces an InvalidCastException.

You *must* use a common type, one that's declared in a separate assembly that is referenced both by your main code and your C++/CLI assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Hans Passant is right. A class is not only defined by its namespace. You could use the [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) design pattern. In the .NET dll, you could create an adapter class to wrap both of the referenced classes. Then you could use the adapter class where you would use each one of the two previous classes. As an example, you would create the `ViperAdapter` class which would replace both the .NET and the C++ `Viper` classes.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

So this is not the "right" answer and Hans Passant's answer is the better one. However, here is what I did because we are so close to release and it would take a lot more effort to get all components using the same model. I simply xml serialized the result I got from the managed C++ dll and then deserialized it as a Data.Model.Viper list. This took less than 1 second and the method will not be called heavily so I think the risk of performance issues should be minimal.